# Программа падает на выходе из функции main

Tags: c

Здравствуйте! Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* vert_mirror(const char* i)
{
    char* s = calloc(sizeof(i)+3, 1);
    char* o = calloc(sizeof(i)+3, 1);
    //char* b = calloc(sizeof(i)+3, 1);
    int   l = 0;

    sprintf(s, "%s", i);

    while (*s++ != '\n') l++;
    while (*s-- != *i);

    while (1) {
        *(s+=l);

        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            sprintf(o, "%s%c", o, *s--);
            //sprintf(o, "%s%c", b, *s--);
        }

        if (*(s+l+1) == 0)
            break;

        sprintf(o, "%s\n", o);
        //sprintf(o, "%s\n", b);

        *(s+=l+1);
    }

    //free(b);
    //free(s);

    o[strlen(o)] = 0;
    return o;
}

int main() {
    char i[] = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop";
    char* s  = vert_mirror(i);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

При запуске падает. Мой действия в `gdb`:

```
Reading symbols from bin\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\codewars\bin\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c
[New Thread 6220.0x1648]
[New Thread 6220.0x13dc]
dcba
hgfe
lkji
ponm
[Inferior 1 (process 6220) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Программа работает, как и должна. Но:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401626: file src\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c, line 42.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\codewars\bin\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c
[New Thread 1260.0x1710]
[New Thread 1260.0x17cc]

Breakpoint 1, main () at src\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c:42
42              char i[] = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop";
(gdb) next
43              char* s  = vert_mirror(i);
(gdb)
44              printf("%s\n", s);
(gdb)
dcba
hgfe
lkji
ponm
45      }(gdb)
__tmainCRTStartup () at C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:334
334     C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v3-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в этом ли причина падений, и, если да, то как ее исправить.

ОС: `Win 10 x64`

Компилирую так: `gcc.exe src\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c -o bin\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c -std=c11 -m32 -g -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: Вы скомпилировали как 32 бита, а запускаете как 64. Уберите -m32.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решена. Может оформите комментарий как ответ?

Comment: При запуске программы Windows пишет: "`Программа "..." не работает`" (если компилировать с флагом `-m32`)

Comment: С расширением `.c` не запускается. Не совсем понял, что значит запустить в mingw.

Comment: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.9.2.exe src\moves_in_squared_strings_1.c -o bin\moves_in_squared_strings_1 -std=c11 -m32` - результат тот же.

Comment: Нет, в поддержке 32 бит нет необходимости, но спасибо за помощь. Успехов и Вам!

Comment: `o[strlen(o)] = 0;` — это не должно работать. Если в конце строки нету нуля, strlen выдаст неправильный результат. А если уже есть, то этот код просто не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в приложении не в том, что она "неправильно скомпилирована", а в том, что в ней допущены грубые ошибки. Разберем. Начнем с этой строки

```
char* s = calloc(sizeof(i)+3, 1);
```

а именно, с этой строки

```
sizeof(i)
```

Почему то многие думают, что длина  будет 20 символов. Но это не так. Там будет 4 (если 32битным компилятором) или 8 (если компилировать 64битным). Поэтому, памяти выделяется мало и весь дальшейший код пишет за пределами. Почему же оно работает? просто повезло, что памяти выделелось достаточно (компилятор знает, что программист любит писать за пределы и выделяет чуточку больше памяти. Также, размер памяти часто округляется в большую сторону до степени двух.

Пофиксим.

поменяем сигнатуру функции, добавим размер

```
char* vert_mirror(const char* i, const int size)
```

теперь вызов будет такой

```
char* s  = vert_mirror(i, sizeof(i));
```

и соответственно выделения памяти

```
char* s = calloc(size+3, 1);
char* o = calloc(size+3, 1);
```

Но дальше есть утечка - память не освободжается. Поэтому эти две строки перепишем чуточку по другому.

```
char* s1 = calloc(size+3, 1);
char* s = s1;
char* o = calloc(size+3, 1);
```

и в самом конце осводбождение

```
free(s1);  // это добавленная строка
o[strlen(o)] = 0;
return o;
```

и конечно в main нужно добавить

```
free(s);
```

После этих четырех строк изменений, программа уже не должна падать и в ней не должно быть утечек.

Пройдемся по другим строках.

```
o[strlen(o)] = 0;
```

эта строка бессмыслена. Она запишет ноль туда, где ноль и так уже есть.

Вот это

```
sprintf(s, "%s", i);
```

хороший способ скопировать строку, но есть проще и лучше:

```
strcpy(s,i);
```

или такое

```
sprintf(o, "%s\n", o);
```

это же обычная конкатенация!

```
strcat(o, "\n");
```

или такое

```
*(s+=l);
```

не вижу ни одной причине разыменовывать и ничего не делать. Лучше так:

```
s+=l;
```

Сюда же и строка

```
*(s+=l+1);
```

Входящий аргумент функции называется `i` - как по мне - плохое имя для строки и для входного аргумента. Тем более, внутри функции уже испольуется такое же имя для цикла.

Я подчистил немного и теперь код выглядит чуточку лучше. Сам алгоритм нужно ещё разобрать, и, возможно, после этого можно будет написать проще

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* vert_mirror(const char* str, const int size)
{
    char* s1 = calloc(size+3, 1);
    char* s = s1;
    char* o = calloc(size+3, 1);
    int   l = 0;

    strcpy(s,str);

    while (*s++ != '\n') l++;
    while (*s-- != *str);

    while (1) {
        s+=l;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            sprintf(o, "%s%c", o, *s--);
        }

        if (*(s+l+1) == 0)
            break;

        strcat(o, "\n");
        s+=l+1;
    }

    free(s1);
    return o;
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop";
    char* s  = vert_mirror(str, sizeof(str));
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за столь исчерпывающий комментарий! Теперь программа работает и с другими аналогичными строками.